# Rails let user upload photo with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have entity `Lead`. I want to be able to upload a picture and save its path to `status_photo` field. I use `carrierwave` gem for photo uploads.

In my model I've mounted `mount_uploader :status_photo, PhotoUploader` (My photouploader definitely works so the problem with code in my controller or view)

Right now I have a form for editing my lead.

```
<%= form_for(@lead) do |f| %>

    phone: <%= @lead.phone %>
    .
    .
    .

   status: <%= select_tag(:status, options_for_select([['0', 0], ['1', 1]], selected: @lead.status )) %>

   photo of car repair process:

   <%= f.file_field :status_photo   %><br/>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
  <% end %>
```

In my controller I have:

```
        def update
        @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])

        if @lead.update_attributes(status: params[:status], status_photo: params[:status_photo] )
          flash[:success] = "Information updated"
          redirect_to leads_url
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end
```

As you can see I also update status field which is updated fine but status_photo doesn't. What do I do?

Comment: I am not sure but it seems like params[:status_photo] gives me empty string